# Как исправить ошибку IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-faq

Код:

```
while True:
        passwd = input('Ведите Пароль:')
        if passwd == '2909':
            print('Добро пожаловать\nПароль верный')
            os.system('cls')
            terminal()
        else:
            print('Пароль не верный')
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "Program.py", line 7
    while True:
              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Что у вас перед `while True:`?

Comment: Надо правильно рассставить отступы.

Comment: Судя по всему там 2 таба вместо 1

Comment: Перед ником добавляйте @, чтобы человеку пришло уведомление, например @gil9red

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за информацию я тут не давно ))) Нуб как говорится

Comment: @Alban На какой строке ??

Comment: @insolor Перед while True: у меня не отступов если вы об этом

Comment: @Коля, если ругается на `while`, значит проблема с отступами до этой строки и в этой строке (у вас явно до этой строки есть код, потому что в ошибке указано что это 7 строка). Возможно у вас для отступов и табы и пробелы используются (нужно использовать что-то одно, желательно пробелы - по pep8).

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Ошибка при выполнении кода: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693946/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Текст ошибки переводится примерно так:

> Ошибка отступа: возврат отступа не соответствует ни одному из внешних уровней отступа

Типичная ситуация, когда возникает такая ошибка: при выходе из блока (уменьшением отступа) мы возвращаемся на уровень не соответствующий ни одному из использовавшихся ранее:

```
if True:  # <-- отступ 0 пробелов
    if False:  # <-- отступ 4 пробела
        pass  # <-- отступ 8 пробелов

 pass # <-- отступ 1 пробел - нет блока, которому бы соответствовал бы этот отступ
```

Получаем ошибку:

```
  File "D:\MyPrograms\test1.py", line 5
    pass # <-- отступ 1 пробел - нет блока, которому бы соответствовал бы этот отступ
                                                                                     ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Обычно редакторы кода (стандартный Notepad к ним не относится) при создании отступов с помощью <kbd>TAB</kbd> и <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> сами «понимают», сколько пробелов перед строкой вам нужно. Создание отступов вручную с помощью пробелов — довольно бессмысленное занятие.

Другая типичная ситуация: смешивание табулиции и пробелов.

```
if True:  # <-- отступ 0 пробелов
    if False:  # <-- отступ 1 таб
        pass  # <-- отступ 1 таб и 4 пробела

    pass # <-- отступ 4 пробела
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "D:\MyPrograms\test1.py", line 5
    pass # <-- отступ 4 пробела
                               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Визуально кажется, что второй `pass` находится на одном уровне с вторым `if`, но фактически это не так: в зависимости от настроек редактора кода ширина 1 табуляции может соответствовать например 8, 4, 2 или 1 пробелу, поэтому интерпретатор даже не будет пытаться понять, какому блоку будет соответствовать новый отступ, а просто выведет ошибку.

Простое правило в данной ситуации: при создании отступов не смешивать табуляцию и пробелы (т.е. использовать только пробелы или только табуляцию для отступов). Еще лучше использовать для отступов только пробелы, как это рекомендует [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).