# Ошибка при выполнении кода: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, python-faq

У меня в ком. строке пишет, что у меня проблемы в 11 строке:

[image: taberror traceback]

Я не могу понять, где тут проблема, отступы делаю, но что-то мешает нормально запустить программу. Вот кстати [сам код](https://gist.github.com/MichaelTroma-X/91d0cfa97c5a5299d1af3c8532dbc1b7.):

```
print('Test Program')
print("This is my proga!")
name = input("Ваше имя: ")

print(name, ", добро пожаловать в темный мир.")

answer = ''
while answer != 'End':
    answer = input("Ты бы хотел взять какое-нибудь оружие? (Y/N/End): ")
   if answer == 'Y':
      print("1-Пулемёт")
      print("2-Гранатомет")
      print("3-Однозарядный пистолет")
      print("4-АА-12")
      answer2 = input("Ваш ответ:")
      if answer2 == '1' or answer2 == '2':
          print("Хороший выбор.")
      elif answer2 == '3':
          print("Плохой выбор, возьми другое.")
      else:
          print("Великолепный выбор.")
  elif answer == 'N':
      print("Ты пацифист? Круто!")
  else:
      print("Ладно, подумай ещё.")
```

Comment: 9-я строка - отступ 4 пробела, 10-я - отступ 3 пробела. Не задавайте здесь вопросы в таком тоне.

Comment: Используйте **только** пробелы для задания отступов. И следите, чтобы их количество было одинаковым для создаваемых блоков кода.

Comment: @andy.37 вопрос с заголовком *"Откуда взялась: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"* вполне уместен на Stack Overflow.  Многие программисты, начиная изучать Питон, могут столкнуться с этой проблемой при копировании примеров из разных источников. Не каждый редактор настроен на использование пробелов для отступов по нажатию на Tab клавишу. Польза вопроса не в сложности, а скольким людям он поможет (пример: [вопрос про print и скобочки в Питоне 3 посетили сотни тысяч людей](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445439/4279))

Comment: Спасибо,у меня всё получилось,просто заменил пробелы на табуляцию

Answer (score 12):

[Яндекс Переводчик](https://translate.yandex.ru/?lang=en-ru&text=TabError%3A%20inconsistent%20use%20of%20tabs%20and%20spaces%20in%20indentation) переводит "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" как:

> TabError: непоследовательное использование табуляции и пробелов в отступах

Что указывает, что у вас отступы (пространство слево от кода) используют как пробелы так и [TAB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

**Не следует смешивать пробелы и табуляцию.** Код, который смешивает пробелы и табуляцию, может выглядеть по разному в разных редакторах (табы разному количеству пробелов могут соответствовать). Визуально отступы, которые вы видите, могут отличаться от отступов, как их оригинальный автор кода задумывал. В свою очередь, это может отличаться от того [как python интерпретатор видит эти отступы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034517/4279). Питон 3 автоматически
[TabError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TabError)
выбрасывает. В Питоне 2, необходимо было [`-tt` опцию командной строки](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t)
добавить, чтобы включить проверку.

[Отступы имеют значение в Питоне](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk). Руководство по стилю кода для Питона
[PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)
рекомендует использовать 4 пробела для каждого отступа:

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Настройте ваше IDE использовать пробелы для отступов по нажатию на
<kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> клавишу. Есть инструменты, которые автоматически
отформатируют ваш код (autopep8,
[yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf), [**black**](https://github.com/psf/black)). Вы можете их
включить в вашем IDE, чтобы они выполнялись при каждом сохранении
кода.

В новом коде табы для отступов не должны быть использованы. Табы можно
использовать в старом коде, который уже использует табы.

Синтаксическая значимость отступов в Питоне гарантирует, что то что вы видите, то и
[получите](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/block_indentation.hawk):

```
if some_condition:
    if another_condition:
        do_something(fancy)
else:
    this_sucks(badluck)
```

Сравните с С кодом, отступы в котором вводят в заблуждение:

```
/*  Warning: XXX bogus C code!  */

if (some condition)
     if (another condition)
         do_something(fancy);
else
    this_sucks(badluck);
```

Здесь `else` принадлежит внутреннему `if`, не смотря на
форматирование.  Ошибки подобного рода встречаются и на практике
(["goto fail" в
iOS](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/apple-goto-fail.html)). В gcc 6 новое предупреждение добавили
[`-Wmisleading-indentation`](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/26/gcc-6-wmisleading-indentation-vs-goto-fail/). В отличии от Питона, в С компилятору сложнее определить правильный ли отступ или нет (приходится эвристики использовать).