# В командной строке выдает TabError

Tags: python

В командной строке:

```
File "C:\Python 3.7\new python\login.py", line 21
name2 = input('Whats your name?')
                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Код:

```
 login = input ('do you want to register(input register) or login(input login)?\n ')
    name = ''
    name2 = ''
    log = False 
    i = 0
    password = ''
    password2 = ''
    while log == True:
        if login == 'register':
            s = open(asas.txt, 'w') 
            name = input('Whats your name?')
            password = input('input password: ')
            password2 = input('repeat password: ')
            if password == password2 and len(name) == 4 and len(password) == 8:
                s.write(name + password)
            elif password != password2:
                print('passwords should be same')
            else:
                print('name should have 4 symbols and password should have 8 symbols')
            s.close()
        if login == 'login':
            open(asas.txt, 'r')
            name2 = input('Whats your name?')
            name = s.read(4)
            if name == name2:
                password = input('input password: ')
                password2 = s.read(8)
            else:
                print('Uncorrect name')
                if password == password2:
                    log = True
                else:
                    print('Uncorrect password')
    s.close()
    print('You have been logined')
```

Comment: гляньте [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693946/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-taberror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-ind)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при выполнении кода: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693946/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-taberror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-ind)

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в коде смешаны табуляция и пробелы в связи с чем возникает ошибка. Рекомендую проверить код.

По поводу использования табов и пробелов в [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) указано, что пробелы являются предпочтительным вариантом для создания отступов.

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.

При этом Python3 запрещает совместное использование табов и пробелов, в Python2 такой код возможен, но интерпретатор пытается преобразовать табы в пробелы.