# Неправильное использование табуляции

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Выдает ошибку:

> TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Все проверял, ничего не помогло, ошибку выдает возле `def get_avard()`

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_idea(self, user_id, idea, username):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `ideas` (`user_id`, `idea`, `username`) VALUES(?,?,?)", (user_id,idea,username))

    def add_avard(self, avard):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `avards` (avard) VALUES(?)", (avard))

    def get_user(self, jid):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `ideas` WHERE `jid` = ?", (jid)).fetchall()

    def get_avard(self, jid):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `avards` WHERE `jid` = ?", (jid)).fetchall()

    def close(self):
        self.connection.close()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при выполнении кода: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693946/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-taberror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-ind)

Comment: проверять мало, надо еще исправлять. От просто проверки ошибки не исчезают.

Comment: Убедитесь, что не намешали табы с пробелами

Comment: Спасибо @vp_arth помогло