# немогу понять в чём ошибка

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, requests, pycharm, bs4

не могу нормально запустить программу из-за этой ошибки:

```
File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\test2\main.py", line 94
    curren = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

**вот код:**

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
from pyowm import OWM
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



#12-17 главное меню(лобби)
#15-50 прогноз погоды


nr = 0

gl = Tk()
gl.title("главное миню")
gl.geometry('420x220')
gl["bg"] = "lightblue"

#прогноз погоды

def pp():

   root = Tk()
   root.title("погода")
   root.geometry("350x250")
   owm = OWM('your_api-key')
   root["bg"] = "lightgreen"


   Label(root, text="Погода в городе", font="Consolas 15 bold", bg="lightblue").pack(pady=5)
   Label(root, text="Укажите название города:", font="Consolas 11 bold", bg="red").pack(pady=5)

   a = Entry(root, width=40)
   a.pack()


   def temp():
      b = str(a.get())
      search = f"Погода в {b}"

      url = f"https://www.google.com/search?&q={search}"

      r = requests.get(url)
      s = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

      update = s.find("div", class_="BNeawe").text

      c = messagebox.showinfo("Прогноз погоды", "В городе " + b + " температура " + update)

      a.delete(first=0, last=10000)

   Button(root, text="Узнать температуру", command=temp).pack(pady=15)

   root.mainloop()

   def vr():
       vr = Tk()
       vr.title("погода")
       vr.geometry("350x250")
       vr["bg"] = "lightblue"
       vr.mainloop()


def v():
   class Currency:
      # Ссылка на нужную страницу
      DOLLAR_RUB = 'https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01NWm6viYijAo3HXYOEQUyDEDtFEw%3A1584716087546&source=hp&ei=N9l0XtDXHs716QTcuaXoAg&q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+%D0%BA+%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E&oq=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80+&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39i70i258j0i131l4j0j0i131l4.3044.4178..5294...1.0..0.83.544.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39.5QL6Ev1Kfk4'
      # Заголовки для передачи вместе с URL
      headers = {
         'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

      current_converted_price = 0
      difference = 5  # Разница после которой будет отправлено сообщение на почту

      def __init__(self):
         # Установка курса валюты при создании объекта
         self.current_converted_price = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))


      # Метод для получения курса валюты
      def get_currency_price(self):
         # Парсим всю страницу
         full_page = requests.get(self.DOLLAR_RUB, headers=self.headers)

         # Разбираем через BeautifulSoup
         soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

         # Получаем нужное для нас значение и возвращаем его
         convert = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DFlfde", "class": "SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})
         return convert[0].text

      def vv(self):
          curren = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))
          messagebox.showinfo("валюта", "Доллар = " + curren + " к рублю ")
      





   # time.sleep(3) # Засыпание программы на 3 секунды
   # self.check_currency()

   currency = Currency()



Button(gl,text="Погода в городе",bg="lightgreen", command=pp).pack(pady=15)#погода
Button(gl,text="Курс валюты", bg="lightgreen", command=v ).pack(pady=15)
Label(gl, text="Dima&Vahtin").pack(pady=15) #логотип в лобби
Label(gl,text="Discord сервер : https://discord.gg/sWHPka87hS").pack(pady=15) #дс сервер в лобби


gl.mainloop()
```

Использую tkinter и с ним tkinter import messagebox,pyowm,requests, и bs4 с BeautifulSoup

Comment: TabError: непоследовательное использование табуляции и пробелов в отступах

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при выполнении кода: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693946/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-taberror-inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-ind)