# IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

Код:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initialize_all_variables())

    for epoch in hm_epochs:
        epoch_loss=0
        for _ in range(int (mnist.train.num_examples/b_s)):
            x,y=mnist.train.next_batch(b_s)
            _,c=sess.run([optimizer,cost]), feed_dict = {x: x, y: y})
            epoch_loss+=c
        print('Epoch : ',epoch,'   complited',hm_epochs,'   loss:' ,epoch_loss)
```

Output:

```
File "C:\Users\neir0\Desktop\py.projects\test_eny_code.py", line 65
sess.run(initialize_all_variables())
   ^IndentationError: expected an indented block
[Finished in 0.142s]
```

Как убрать ошибку?

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696367/207200)

Comment: Проследить чтобы везде было по 4 пробела в отступе, т.к. в питоне блоки отделяются отступами, а не фигурным скобкам (`{` `}`) как в других языках

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов: ошибки в самом коде нет — ошибка в способе, которым вы выполняете код. В интерактивных средах пустая строка может рассматриваться как завершение блока, поэтому следующая строчка с отступом вызывает похожую IndentationError:

```
>>> if 1:
...     print('no empty line')
... 
no empty line
>>>     print('after empty line')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('after empty line')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Этот же код, выполненный обычным способом (из `.py` файла или в интерактивных средах, которые принимают блоки кода таких как ipython, ptpython), [не вызывает ошибки](https://ideone.com/n0siCI).